# How set an image in Android ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I need to show a image, when i press a button on my application.

I'm trying with:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
imageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.loading);
```

but it shows an error.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an error log that you could add to the question? Would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: The method setImageDrawable(Drawable) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import package_name.R.drawable;

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
imageView.setImageResource(drawable.loading);
```

OR

you can set the image from the start, set it to invisible and when you want to show it just change the visibility property.

Answer (score 0):

for future visitors:

sometime `setImageDrawable(Drawable)` method show an error like:

> The method setImageDrawable(Drawable) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (int)

can try following codes:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image);
imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
```

---------    OR can try  this    ------------------

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(YourActivity.this, R.drawable.your_image));
```

hope it work for you.